# HP ProLiant server - PSU error despite replacing PSUs

Tags: hardware, hp-proliant, power-supply-unit

We have a **HP ProLiant ML350 G6** server causing us a few problems.

The main symptom was that every so often we would find the server simply powered off. We turned the machine back on and investigated to find that one of the PSU fans had started whistling and blowing a lot of air out of the back of the server. At the same time, we noticed a flashing amber light on the front of the machine:

[image: Server front LEDs]

Presuming that our PSUs were at fault, we replaced them *both*. The system started up fine and everything seemed to be working OK. No amber light, no whistling or excessive blowing.

However, less than 24 hours later, we've got a repeat of exactly the same symptoms. The machine hasn't actually turned itself off this time but the amber light is back, as is the whistling.

We then took the side panel off to investigate the problem further and found that LED in position 2 on the motherboard (PSU 2) has a solid amber LED.

[image: Motherboard LED position 2]

We have had a look at HP SystemManager but this simply says that our system is fully healthy - no component problems.

What else could the problem be if not the PSUs?

Comment: Two things, that server's no longer supported by HPE, you should plan to move off it soon. Secondly this could easily be a motherboard error, the only way to tell would be to swap it out.

Comment: We're changing our entire server infrastructure in August, but we need this to last until then!

Comment: It may be a power save manager trouble. Try to assign maximum performance mode in BIOS settings and disable C-states CPU option there.

Answer (score 1):

You could try upgrading the firmware of your server.

Make sure the system BIOS is current. Replace system board if it continues to be a problem. This could be a sign of failure of that particular PSU slot.

I would also take a closer look at the ILO or system IML log to see what is actually being recorded. The server has enough sensors that it will tell you exactly what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes switching the PSUs helps in HP servers.